# Livereload of index.html with Gulp

Tags: livereload, gulp

I am attempting to have my browser update when I make a change to index.html in the root of my project. Livereloading is working fine when updating the CSS. 
I have removed the efforts I made to get this working in my gulpfile.js, below...

Thanks!

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass'),
autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
minifycss = require('gulp-minify-css'),
jshint = require('gulp-jshint'),
uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
rename = require('gulp-rename'),
clean = require('gulp-clean'),
concat = require('gulp-concat'),
notify = require('gulp-notify'),
cache = require('gulp-cache'),
livereload = require('gulp-livereload'),
lr = require('tiny-lr'),
server = lr();

gulp.task('styles', function() {
return gulp.src('components/sass/style.scss')
.pipe(sass({ style: 'expanded' }))
.pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1', 'ios 6',         'android 4'))
.pipe(gulp.dest(''))
.pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
.pipe(minifycss())
.pipe(gulp.dest(''))
.pipe(livereload(server))
.pipe(notify({ message: 'Styles task complete' }));
});

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
return gulp.src('components/js/*.js')
// .pipe(jshint('.jshintrc'))
.pipe(jshint.reporter('default'))
.pipe(concat('main.js'))
.pipe(gulp.dest('js'))
.pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
.pipe(uglify())
.pipe(gulp.dest('js'))
.pipe(livereload(server))
.pipe(notify({ message: 'Scripts task complete' }));

});

gulp.task('images', function() {
return gulp.src('components/img/*')
.pipe(imagemin({ optimizationLevel: 5, progressive: true, interlaced: true }))
.pipe(gulp.dest('img'))
.pipe(livereload(server))
.pipe(notify({ message: 'Images task complete' }));
});

// gulp.task('clean', function() {
//   return gulp.src(['css', 'js', 'img'], {read: false})
//     .pipe(clean());
// });

gulp.task('watch', function() {

server.listen(35729, function (err) {
if (err) {
return console.log(err)
};
// Watch .scss files
gulp.watch('components/sass/*.scss', ['styles']);
// Watch .js files
gulp.watch('components/js/*.js', ['scripts']);
// Watch image files
gulp.watch('components/img/*', ['images']);
});    
});

// gulp.task('default', ['clean'], function() {
gulp.task('default', function() {
gulp.start('styles', 'scripts', 'images');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a better way to do what you want to do.

Have you thought about maybe using an instance of `express` with `livereload`?

The alternative is to use `gulp-connect` which will make what you're trying to do much easier.  In either case, instead of invoking `livereload` within tasks, handle livereloading within the task that sets up your server. The general idea is that you set a watch task on your files that you want livereloading and then reload on changes.

```
gulp.task('serve', function(event) {
    connect.server({
        root: destinations.docs,
        port: 1987,
        livereload: true
    });
    // sets up a livereload that watches for any changes in the root
    watch({glob: [sources.html, sources.styles]})
        .pipe(connect.reload());
});
```

I've experimented with both ways and `gulp-connect` is a much easier option. Regardless, I've written two gulp boilerplates which you can see at https://github.com/jh3y/gulp-boilerplate-v2 and https://github.com/jh3y/gulp-boilerplate .

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 5):

You can try to put put your html files into a subfolder like `components/html` and use a task similar to the styles task:

```
gulp.task('html', function() {
    return gulp.src('components/html/**/*.html')
        .pipe(gulp.dest(''))
        .pipe(livereload(server))
        .pipe(notify({ message: 'HTML task complete' }));
});
```

Your default task should look like:

```
// gulp.task('default', ['clean'], function() {
gulp.task('default', function() {
    gulp.start('styles', 'scripts', 'images', 'html');
});
```

And modify your watch task:

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {

    server.listen(35729, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err)
        };
        // Watch .scss files
        gulp.watch('components/sass/*.scss', ['styles']);
        // Watch .js files
        gulp.watch('components/js/*.js', ['scripts']);
        // Watch image files
        gulp.watch('components/img/*', ['images']);
        // Watch html files
        gulp.watch('components/html/**/*.html', ['html']);
    });
});
```

Ciao
Ralf

Comment: It works for me but all html files are reloaded and not only the files that have change. Any idea to reload only what have change ?

Answer (score 2):

Manual browser-sync reload of specific file types in project root using current gulp syntax as of 4/2016 referenced here:

https://www.browsersync.io/docs/gulp/#gulp-manual-reload

EXAMPLE: Add lines below the SCSS reference to watch HTML and HTM files with browser-sync:

```
gulp.watch("./scss/*.scss", ['sass']);
gulp.watch("*.html").on("change", reload);
gulp.watch("*.htm").on("change", reload);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a livereload or express instance, you can do something like the following which i use in my laravel 5 project with elixir gulp extension in combination with [live.js](http://livejs.com).

extend elixir

`elixir.extend('livereloader',function(message) {
    gulp.task('livereloader',function(){
        return gulp.src('public/js/livereloader.js')
            .pipe(insert.append(''))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('public/js/'));
    });
    this.registerWatcher("livereloader", 'resources/views/**/*.php');
    return this.queueTask('livereloader');
});`

use the task

`mix.livereloader();`

simple enough. even without livereload or express (don't see why i should use them at all ...)